# Redirection/Piping in C Bugs

Tags: c, redirect, piping, nano

Ok, in this code I have 2 primary problems.

1:  The parent doesn't wait for the child to print before returning to main and printing.  I included a waitpid() but it doesn't seem to be working how I expected.

2. When I redirect, I create the file fine, but nano and vim don't "see" the file, Gedit however can (so I know my output is being sent correctly)

The flow of this function:

A string is input, the string is checked for a trailing & (if it exists, it is removed and the background flag is updated).

Then the string is tokenized on  '|'
Each token is tokenized on '<'  and  '>'
Then each string from that is tokenized on ' '
The resulting char ** is executed with the output/input being redirected based off the results of the above tokenizations.

```
    void execute_command(char * s)
    {
        printf("\n");
        int fd[3][2]; //  since we are guaranteed each type of redirection will be used only once, I only need 3 pipes:  <  >  and |
        //int fd[2];    
        int res;
        pid_t pid;
        int status;
        int stdin_c = dup(0);
        int stdout_c = dup(1);
        int i;
        int background = 0;

        for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++);
            if(s[i-1] == '&')
            {
                background = 1;
                s[i-1] = '\0';
            }

        char ** piped = token_pipe(s);
        char ** left_a;
        char ** right_a;
        int output = 0;
        int input = 0;

        for(i = 0; piped[i] != NULL; i++)
        {
            left_a = token_leftarrow(piped[i]);
            right_a = token_rightarrow(piped[i]);
            if(left_a[1] != NULL)   
            {
                free(piped[i]);
                piped[i] = calloc(strlen(left_a[0]) + 1, sizeof(char));
                strcpy(piped[i], left_a[0]);
                fd[0][0] = open(left_a[1], O_RDONLY);
                input = i;      
            }

            if(right_a[1] != NULL)  
            {
                free(piped[i]);
                piped[i] = calloc(strlen(left_a[0]) + 1, sizeof(char));
                strcpy(piped[i], right_a[0]);
                fd[1][1] = open(right_a[1], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666);
                output = i;
            }   
        }

        char ** spaced = token_space(piped[0]);
        char ** spaced2 = NULL;
        if(piped[1] != NULL)
        {
            spaced2 = token_space(piped[1]);
            res = pipe(fd[2]);
            if(res < 0)
            {
                printf("Pipe Failure\n");
                exit(-1);
            }// end if
        }   

        if(fork() == 0)
        {
            if(background == 1)
               setpgid(0, 0);
            if(piped[1] != NULL)
            {
                close(fd[2][1]);
                close(0);
                dup(fd[2][0]);

                if(output == 1 && right_a[1] != NULL)
                {
                    dup2(fd[1][1], 1);
                    close(fd[1][1]);
                }         

                execvp(spaced2[0], spaced2);
                perror("Invalid Command");
                exit(-1);
            }
            else
            {   
                if(input == 0 || output == 0)
                {
                    if(right_a[1] != NULL)
                    {
                        dup2(fd[1][1], 1);
                        close(fd[1][1]);
                    }
                    if(left_a[1] != NULL)
                    {
                        dup2(fd[0][0], 0);
                        close(fd[0][0]);
                    }

                }   

                execvp(spaced[0], spaced);
                perror("Invalid command\n");
                exit(-1);
            }
        }
    else
    {
        if(piped[1] != NULL)
        {
            if((pid = fork()) == 0)
            {
                close(fd[2][0]);
                close(1);
                dup(fd[2][1]); 
                if(input == 0 && left_a[1] != NULL)
                {
                    dup2(fd[0][0], 0);
                    close(fd[0][0]);
                }     

                execvp(spaced[0], spaced);
                perror("Invalid Command");
                exit(-1);
            }
            else
                if(background == 0)
                    waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);

        }
        else
            if(background == 0)
                wait(NULL);


        close(fd[2][0]);
        close(fd[2][1]);
        close(fd[0][0]);
        close(fd[1][1]);
        dup2(stdin_c, 0);
        dup2(stdout_c, 1);

      } 


    }
```

Comment: maybe if the code was commented, so we knew what was trying to be accomplished at each code block, then we could help.  As it is, I see (what I think) are numerous bad logic sequences,  just as a simple start, the call to waitpid() has the WNOHANG parameter, so it will not wait for the child to complete

Comment: the fork() function has three exit cases, not just two.  I.E. the code needs to always check the error cases and allow for them, rather than assuming that everything works

Comment: perhaps reading the system function descriptions would help.   BTW: there are three standard file descriptors that need to be duped,  stdin, stdout, stderr

Comment: I apologize about the commenting,   I'll try it without the WNOHANG parameter, and I don't care about stderr in this situation.